# Are the Serpent Test Vectors incorrect?

Tags: block-cipher, test-vectors, serpent

I have recently written an implementation of Serpent and was testing it against known vectors to no avail.  Using 256-bit key, I compared my encryption to the test vectors located here:

[http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~biham/Reports/Serpent/Serpent-256-128.verified.test-vectors](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/%7Ebiham/Reports/Serpent/Serpent-256-128.verified.test-vectors)

For some reason, I match none of these test vectors, and I do not know why.  I downloaded the Python implementation found here:

[https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~fms27/serpent/serpent.py.html](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Efms27/serpent/serpent.py.html)

The Python implementation agreed with me and disagreed with the published test vectors.  I did, however, find two files in folder Floppy 4 (ecb_tbl.txt) and (ecb_iv.txt) from the full submission package ([http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~rja14/Papers/serpent.tar.gz](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Erja14/Papers/serpent.tar.gz)) which I completely agree with. If I put in the given 256-bit key and the given plaintexts, I do achieve the correct encrypted ciphertexts.

Are the test vectors published on biham's website incorrect, or is there perhaps something I am missing?  If they are wrong, why are they still up and way easier to find than the ones I matched with?

As an example, on Biham's site,

key=8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
plain=00000000000000000000000000000000
cipher=A223AA1288463C0E2BE38EBD825616C0

But both my implementation and the Python reference implementation give:

cipher=abed96e766bf28cbc0ebd21a82ef0819

I think it has something to do with this NESSIE format, but so far, I have been unable to determine if that is true and what exactly that means.

Comment: According to [this](https://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~biham/Reports/Serpent/), there are two versions of Serpent. It seems that your test vectors are for Serpent-1, and it could be that your code is for Serpent-0. The changes are in the key schedule, so that would explain why you get correct results for the all-zero key, but not others. I do not make it an answer, because I'm far from sure.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback on this, but I already considered it.  My code is not for Serpent-0. I checked this by using the original Python implementation of Serpent-0 and found it gives completely different ciphertext than the Serpent-1 reference, which I am checking my implementation against.  The Serpent-0 ciphertext does not match any of the available test vectors I have found, even the ones I noted that I match above using my implementation.

Comment: probable duplicate of https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/20306/bouncy-jdk-1-51-serpent-kat-tests-vs-nessie-vectors/20310#20310

Comment: Does above link answer your question, and if it doesn't, can you please indicate what's missing from the answer? I read everything in full, and it does seem to come down to the same thing.

Comment: Actually, it kind of does.  Why the heck does NESSIE have a flipped byte order?  I ran the key 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080 (flipped byte order) and got the ciphertext above but also in flipped byte order.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Richie Frame pointing out this is basically a duplicate of question

[Bouncy jdk 1.51 Serpent KAT tests vs Nessie vectors](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/20306/bouncy-jdk-1-51-serpent-kat-tests-vs-nessie-vectors/20310#20310)

I discovered the NESSIE writes their key, plaintext, and ciphertext test vectors for Serpent in reversed byte-order (but it's not little endian inside the bytes).  So, on Biham's site,
[https://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~biham/Reports/Serpent/Serpent-256-128.verified.test-vectors](https://www.cs.technion.ac.il/%7Ebiham/Reports/Serpent/Serpent-256-128.verified.test-vectors)
, the first test vector, 

key=8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
plain=00000000000000000000000000000000
cipher=A223AA1288463C0E2BE38EBD825616C0

only works if I use my implementation in reverse byte order; that is, I have to input the key:0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080,

and I get the above ciphertext in reverse byte order:

cipher:  c0165682bd8ee32b0e3c468812aa23a2

Verifying this with set 3, vector 130:

key= 8282828282828282828282828282828282828282828282828282828282828282
plaintext = 82828282828282828282828282828282
ciphertext= AAA92B00896FE228BDF5AA3BA534CA44

Since the key and plaintext are reversible by byte order, I can put this key and plaintext in and expect the ciphertext in reverse byte order.  My implementation yields:

44ca34a53baaf5bd28e26f89002ba9aa.

This checks out!